# 3 variables and conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability

Following a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/several-questions-about-conditional-probability), lets say we now have 3 variables:

$L$, $B$, $S$:

```
     S
   /   \
  L     B
```

So 
$L$ depends on $S$
$B$ depends on $S$

$P(S) =$ 0.5
$P( \lnot S) =$ 0.5

$L$ that depends on $S$:

$P(L|S) =$ 0.10
$P( \lnot L|S) =$ 0.90
$P(L| \lnot S) =$ 0.01
$P( \lnot L| \lnot S) =$ 0.99

$B$ that depends on $S$:

$P(B|S) =$ 0.60
$P( \lnot B|S) =$ 0.40
$P(B| \lnot S) =$ 0.30
$P( \lnot B| \lnot S) =$ 0.70

I have gotten

$P(L) =$ 0.055    $P(\lnot L) =$ 0.945

$P(B) =$ 0.45     $P(\lnot B) =$ 0.55

As the previos question to get 
$P(S)$ after I observe that $P(L)=1$
$P(S∣L)=  P(L∣S)P(S)  / P(L) =$ (0.10)(0.5)  / (0.055)  = 0.9091
so
$P(S)=$ 0.9091

Similarly when we have $P(B)=$1
$P(S∣B)=  P(B∣S)P(S)  / P(B) =$ (0.40)(0.5)  / (0.45)  = 0.3636
so
$P(S)=$ 0.3636

But What do you do when you observe both events:

$P(L)=$1  and
$P(B)=$1

How do you modify the above formula to get $P(S)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first we don't know the outcomes of $L$ and $B$:
$$P_{prior} = \begin{matrix}
P_{prior}(S \land       L \land       B) & P_{prior}(\lnot S \land       L \land       B) \\
P_{prior}(S \land       L \land \lnot B) & P_{prior}(\lnot S \land       L \land \lnot B) \\
P_{prior}(S \land \lnot L \land       B) & P_{prior}(\lnot S \land \lnot L \land       B) \\
P_{prior}(S \land \lnot L \land \lnot B) & P_{prior}(\lnot S \land \lnot L \land \lnot B)
\end{matrix}$$
$$ = \begin{matrix}
0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.6 & 0.5 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.3 \\
0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.4 & 0.5 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.7 \\
0.5 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.6 & 0.5 \cdot 0.99 \cdot 0.3 \\
0.5 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.4 & 0.5 \cdot 0.99 \cdot 0.7 \\
\end{matrix}$$

We then observe L and B.

$$P_{posterior} = \begin{matrix}
0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.6 & 0.5 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.3 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \cdot \frac{1}{0.5 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.6 + 0.5 \cdot 0.01 \cdot 0.3}$$
$$ = \begin{matrix}
20/21 & 1/21 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}$$

$$P_{posterior}(S) = \frac{P_{prior}(S \land       L \land       B)}{P_{prior}(S \land       L \land       B) + P_{prior}(\lnot S \land       L \land       B)} = 20/21 \approx 0.95$$